# Accessing files in the shell script

Tags: shell, wc

i am trying to access file email.txt in the script (directory of .txt file and the script is same)

```
!#bin/bash
total="$(wc -l < email.txt | tr -d ' ')"
echo "$total"
```

it's showing permission denied. 
Thankyou for any help

Comment: what are the permissions on the file? can you change them or do they need to remain what they are?

Comment: email.txt is just a normal text file, i havent set any permissions on it (they would remain same as they are, if any)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's at least one syntax error on your first character. Next give your script execute permissions,

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

total="$(wc -l < email.txt | tr -d ' ')"
echo "$total"
$ chmod 755 test.sh
$ ./test.sh
0
```

But then I have an empty "email.txt" file.

Comment: you are setting the permissions for test.sh, but the file that is needed to be accessed is email.txt, dont we need to set permissions for that

Comment: @user2831683 You must have permission to read the file, else how did you create it and the script in the same folder?

Comment: text file is not being created through the script, it is just a text file.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Unless it was created by a script run by a different user, you should be fine; if otherwise, there are some choices beyond giving it world read permission (which will work of course).